# makefile: reuse multiple recipes

Tags: makefile

I want to use the same complex block of recipes for an implicit and a normal rule.
Also, I want make to echo the next command AFTER thre previous command executed.

Make does not allow mixing implicit and normal rules.

Desired output:

```
$ make foo bar.abc
echo a
a
echo b
b
echo a
a
echo b
b
```

This won't work:

```
%.abc foo:
    echo a
    echo b
```

This will work:

```
CMD = echo a && echo b
foo:
    $(CMD)

%.abc:
    $(CMD)
```

but the output is not what I want:

```
$ make foo bar.abc
echo a && echo b
a
b
echo a && echo b
a
b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `define` to assign multi-line values to variables:

```
define CMD
echo a
echo b
endef
```